# Solr - Find whole numberin float field

Tags: solr, indexing, field, trie, fieldtype

I need some guidance on how to properly index a field representing money.
I need 130 to match 130.64.  I tried the trie float configuration below.

```
<fieldType name="float" class="solr.TrieFloatField" precisionStep="8" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
```

When I search in the field for 130 I get no results. I have tried increasing and decreasing the precision to no avail.

How do I get this to index parts of the number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly make the float field (TrieFloatField) match the whole number part (by just passing the "number"). What you have to do is a range query over the number:

fieldname:{130 TO 131} OR 130

Answer (score 0):

Just index it as a textTield and then you can match it with wildcard query or you can make ngrams and match query on those.

Comment: This would work, but I also need to search it in range.  I could create another field and copy but I really don't want to duplicate the data.